# Like dislike button like YouTube using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

**HTML**

```
<i class="fas fa-thumbs-up" onclick="like()"></i>
<i class="fas fa-thumbs-down" onclick="dislike()"></i>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var color1 = document.getElementsByClassName('fa-thumbs-up')[0];
var color2 = document.getElementsByClassName('fa-thumbs-down')[0];

function like(){
  if(color1.style.color== "black"){
    color1.style.color= "blue";
  }
  else if(color1.style.color == "blue"){
    color1.style.color = "black";
  }
  else if (color2.style.color == "blue") {
    color2.style.color = "black";
  }
}

function dislike(){
  if (color2.style.color == "black") {
    color2.style.color = "blue";
  }
  else if (color2.style.color == "blue") {
    color2.style.color = "black";
  }
  else if (color1.style.color == "blue") {
    color1.style.color = "black";
  }
}
```

Please help me to make the buttons like YouTube. My code do not working. I need to turn one button blue when I click on it and if click on another button then the 1st one should turn into the previous color.

Comment: `color1.style.color` returns a RGB color, not the color name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is way simplier than you did. Just use the following code for your functions:

```
function like() {
    color1.style.color = color1.style.color === 'blue' ? 'black': 'blue';
    color2.style.color = 'black';
}

function dislike() {
    color1.style.color = 'black';
    color2.style.color = color2.style.color === 'red' ? 'black' : 'red';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

USE THIS CODE

```
function like() {
  if(color1.style.color == "blue") {
    color1.style.color = "black";
  } else {
    color1.style.color = "blue";
  }
  color2.style.color = "black";
}

function dislike() {
  if (color2.style.color == "blue") {
    color2.style.color = "black";
  } else {
    color2.style.color = "blue";
  }
  color1.style.color = "black";
}
```